# How can I disable jetbrain annotations?

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a way to disable Jetbrain R# from inserting JetBrain annotation?
For example when I add R# "null check" I don't want the NotNull annotationt which 
forces me to be linked to the annotation dll

Comment: ReSharper doesn't insert annotations unless you ask it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You have done one or both of the following two things:

1. Added a reference to the Jetbrains assembly to your project(s)
2. Added a copy of the annotations attributes source code to your project(s)

To avoid having R# inserting those attributes, you need to remove either or both of the above two sources for these attributes. If R# can't see that the attributes are available, it won't add them to your code.

Note that if you want to keep using those attributes (and the other attributes in the annotations namespace), but don't want to have a reference to the assembly, you can add a copy of the source code for those attributes to your project.

Comment: I have asked for the R# null checking on a method parameter. what I have wanted has that R# will only add the check of the null value, but it has also added [NotNull] attribute. I want him only to add the check without the attribute

Comment: And as I said, since the attributes are available, ReSharper will add them. Make them unavailable.

Comment: There's actually a third option for this.  If you're referencing another assembly that was built with the annotations source, then ReSharper will find them and use them.  

In my case, I couldn't figure out why the annotations were being added but when I decompiled the `[NotNull]` attribute, I found it was coming from a library provided to me by another team.  They had used ReSharper and as a result the annotations were pulled in with their library.  

Unfortunately, there doesn't really seem to be a way to fix this without updating the offending library to use a ref instead of a source copy.